# Selenium IDE: Nested variables

Tags: variables, nested, selenium-ide

Is it possible to evaluate an expression with nested variables in Selenium IDE?
Example:

```
store | 2 | scenario
store | $10 | data${scenario}Cost
```

So `data2Cost = $10`

```
store | ${data{$scenario}Cost} | ${scenario}Result
echo  | ${scenario}Result |
```

Which returns `2Result = ${data2Cost}` opposed to `2Result = $10`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [storeEval](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0.1/reference.html#storeEval) to store the evaluated expression into an variable
This [tutorial](http://www.questionselenium.com/2012/10/echo-storeeval-and-storedvars.html) helped me achieving that

```
|store | 2 | scenario | 
|store | $10 | data${scenario}Cost | 
|storeEval | storedVars['data${scenario}Cost'] | ${scenario}Result | 
|storeEval | storedVars['${scenario}Result'] | MainResult | 
|echo | ${MainResult} |
```

[image]

Comment: Apologies Madhan, my example was not clear. I have adjusted it to better reflect what I am looking for. HTH

Comment: @JulieCalboutin Updated my answer check it

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks very much Madhan. Unfortunately that tutorial is blocked from my work PC, so will definitely check it out at home.